# Add 2 years to date

Tags: php, date, datetime

I can't seem to work out why this isn't working.

I may of done this completely wrong but hoping someone can help.

I have a date and I want to add 2 years to that date. When I run my code it only echo's the date I started with.

Does anyone know where I have gone wrong?
I want to only use the date in $start_date not today's date.

```
$start_date = "2013-05-06 13:18:56";
    $targetDate = date($start_date, strtotime('+2 Years'));
    echo $targetDate;
```

Comment: That's not how `date()` works. Read the documentation closely: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want this:

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 years', strtotime($from_date)));
```

For the options for the date format, check out the [documentation](http://www.php.net/date).

Comment: Your missing a ) at the end of your code, once I added that it worked! Thanks heaps.

Answer (score 2):

Another option for you is to use the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes built into PHP:-

```
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', "2013-05-06 13:18:56");
var_dump($date);
$interval = new DateInterval('P2Y');
$date->add($interval);
var_dump($date);
```

The output from this is something like:-

```
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2013-05-06 13:18:56' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
object(DateTime)[1]
  public 'date' => string '2015-05-06 13:18:56' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/London' (length=13)
```

Comment: Why is this not upvoted at least, the DateTime class is preferred

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
string date ( string $format [, int $timestamp = time() ] )
```

the first parameter is a date format, not the actual date you want to operate on.

Take a look at [`DateTime::add`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php).